# Office Interop no funciona en Windows Server 2016

Tags: .net, interop

Buen día, estimados:

¿Qué librerías o recursos necesito para dejar operando correctamente una aplicación de .NET que utiliza **Office Interop** en un **Windows Server 2016**?

El error que no me permite continuar es:

> No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con
>   CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} debido al siguiente
>   error: 80080005 Error en la ejecución de servidor (Excepción de
>   HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

Cabe mencionar que se instaló la misma versión de Office que en mi ambiente de desarrollo, en el cual la aplicación opera sin problema alguno. Estuve checando en algunos foros el tema del registro de DLL's el cual ya completé, así como los permisos del usuario IIS para ejecutar el servicio COM.

Gracias de antemano.